# XML not generating for twilio in ruby file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, twilio

I am building a phone-number verification app using Twilio. Following [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/rest) tutorial closely. However, I am unable to generate a valid XML like how this [specific page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/ruby/twiml/say-response) says. How can I fix this?

My main problem is that I am unable to get Twilio to read the TwiML document which I set up in twilio-quickstart.rb. I have run ruby twilio-quickstart.rb and exposed my port using ngrok. On the browser, I can see the words in TwiML tags but in the call, keep getting Application Error. Twilio logs indicate HTTP retrieval failure with this message.

> An attempt to retrieve content from
>   http://adfsfsdf.ngrok.io/hello-monkey returned the HTTP status code
>   404.

Suspecting an error with the way the XML document is generate (I may be wrong) 
In the browser...Instead of getting this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Say>Hello Monkey</Say>
</Response>
```

I am getting this...

> Press 1 to verify your number

Whereas one of the [example urls](http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient) given shows the xml page clearly.

Just to be sure - I have set up my ngrok properly.

How can I generate the XML document properly? Or, how I can overcome the HTTP retrieval error that Twilio logs are showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There are a few things that could be going on here, so I might not be right to start with, but we can work to get this sorted for you.

The error you're getting from Twilio is a 404, meaning that Twilio can't find the URL it's looking for. If you can hit your own endpoint and get a response then there is probably something wrong between you and Twilio.

I'm not sure how you've set ngrok up, but that may be the issue. Everytime you restart ngrok you get a new subdomain, so you may need to update your URL on your Twilio number.

In the case of not seeing the XML in the browser, it's because the quickstart doesn't set the right content type. You can fix that, in Sinatra, by setting the content type, and you'd do so like this:

```
get '/hello-monkey' do
  content_type "text/xml"
  Twilio::TwiML::Response.new do |r|
    r.Say 'Hello Monkey'
  end.text
end
```

Let me know if this helps at all.

Comment: thanks - specifying content_type helped with seeing xml in the browser. However, I still get the same error. I have specified the url to read the twiml from (this is the ngrok url which works in my browser but somehow can't be picked up by twilio). Checked that the ngrok url is consistent too..

Comment: Is the phone number set to GET or POST? Make sure that matches with the route in Sinatra

Comment: The phone number is set to POST - how do I ensure it matches with the route in Sinatra? Is it by setting the url to the right one (i.e. ngrok one) after specifying the from/to fields?

Comment: From the example you linked to, and code I used in my answer, the Sinatra route you are using will respond to a GET request (`get '/hello-monkey' do`). You can either change that from `get` to `post` or change the number config in your Twilio portal from POST to GET. Just as long as they match up, your request should go through.

Comment: got it, the sync of get and post fixed it.

Comment: Fantastic! Glad you're all sorted!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103070/discussion-between-rpv-and-philnash).